# Upgrading to FreeForm Pro 4.1.2 Styling not working

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a testing server that duplicates our live server and I updated our FreeForm 3 to 4.1.2 on the testing server and everything went smoothly. When I deployed those changes to our live server the styling for the CP area is broken and I am unable to use the new composer for 4.1.2

I have included screen shots so you can see what is happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[image: Screen Shot of the testing server]

[image: Screen Shot of the live server]

Answer (score 2):

Check the console for missing files or errors. Most likely it's not loading all the assets for you.

Comment: We use Github to track and deploy changes from our testing server to the live server so when I do a deployment, it uploads the files from the testing server to the correct location on the live server. 

I checked the console and I am not receiving any errors from the install and it states that I have updated to 4.1.2.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yes and I have reviewed it on different computers/browsers and it is still the same.

Comment: And there is no errors in the console? I suggest manually uploading the latest Freeform files to the server to see if that fixes it.

Comment: That worked! GitHub was ignoring all the css files since our site is setup with sass files. Thanks for your help!